# Update avg value in table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm tring to update my mark average by adding to it some value.

My table of admited student contains (NOSTUDENT, COURSECODE, SEMESTER, NOGROUPE,MARK) Columns.

My View : AverageByGroupe contains the average of mark of students following that course in corresponding semester.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AverageByGroup  AS
SELECT COURSCODE, NOGROUPE, SEMESTER, AVG(MARK) AS AVGMARK
FROM ADMITED_TABLE GROUP BY COURSECODE,NOGROUPE,SEMESTER;
```

**Question:** I want to update the average mark for a given course, group, semester by 10, but AVGMARK is note a column, What it the correct UPDATE syntax.

**What I have tried:**

```
UPDATE ADMITED_TABLE
SET AVG(MARK) = SELECT( (AVG(MARK) + 10)
FROM ADMITED_TABLE WHERE COURSCODE = 'AAAA' 
AND NOGROUP = 2
AND SEMESTER = 'AUTMN');

Error:
Error de command ligne: 2 Column: 8
Rapport of error -
Erreur SQL : ORA-00927: missing equal sign
00927. 00000 -  "missing equal sign"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

**Edit**:
To be more clear, this is a mutate table so what I want to use is a INSTEAD OF INSERT TRIGGER wich fire every time the mark average is chaged by adjusting that cours student mark.

For the select syntax error, I included select in (

```
UPDATE ADMITED_TABLE
SET AVG(MARK) = (SELECT (AVG(MARK) + 10)
FROM ADMITED_TABLE WHERE COURSCODE = 'AAAA' 
AND NOGROUP = 2
AND SEMESTER = 'AUTMN');
```

Error:

```
ORA-00927: missing equal sign
00927. 00000 -  "missing equal sign"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: you are trying to update the average of a column in the table,which isn't possible.

Comment: You have syntax error - parenthesis should include SELECT. Can you post what error you get after fixing?

Comment: It is not possible, this is a view, you cannot directly modify the value from this view unless you writes all the selected column to a new table. And then execute the below query I gave to you. (You also have some syntax errors in your query)

Comment: What if I update students marks to equal the new average mark. Is this a good idea,

Comment: Firstly, the ethical considerations of this request should mean you should polish off your resume and leave now. Secondly, your view contains the average, and it looks like if you want to raise the average by 10 points, you will need to update the underlying table. No, I won't help with the math to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE NewADMITED_TABLE`

`SET AVGMARK = (AVGMARK + 10)` -- this is not a DERIVED column anymore

`WHERE COURSCODE = 'AAAA'`

`AND NOGROUP = 2`

`AND SEMESTER = 'AUTMN`